# "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::save()"

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-filesystem

I want stored data in database with image path. I write following function but  following error occur.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::save()

which namespace i add?

```
function insert(Request $req)
   {

       $user=new file;    
       $user->name=Input::get('name');
       $user->address=Input::get('address');
       $user->created_at=Input::get(now());
       $user->updated_at=Input::get(now());

       if(Input::hasFile('image'))
       {
        $file=Input::file('image');
        $file->move(public_path().'/',$file->getClientOriginalName());  
        $user->photo=$file->getClientOriginalName();    
       }

       $user->save();

       return redirect('/');

   }
```

Comment: your `save()` method is used for $user, but the $user is created as a File, is there something wrong in the beginning when you declare an instance of User?

Comment: why you use $user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead?

```
$user = new App\User;
```

The reason is, in your first line, `$user=new file;` creates an instance of [`Illuminate\Support\Facades\File`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Facades/File.html), which does not have a `save()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use File aliases in top of controller 
Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,

```
$move = File::move($old_path, $new_path);
```

File is for save file in directory and you can you instance of user for save 
user data

```
$user = New App\User();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to just changed here

`$user=new file;`

**to**

```
$user = new User();
```